# How to create a row in an intermediate relationship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tables Users, Locations and Follows, where Users have_many locations :through => :follows. Follows belongs_to both users and locations. I want to add a row into the Follows table--that is, create a Following relationship between a user and a location.

I'm not sure how to do this, or if I'm implementing Follows right:

```
class CreateFollows < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :follows |do| t
      t.references :user_id
      t.references :location_id
      t.timestamps
     end
   end
end
```

And the code I'm trying to use to add a Follows relationship, given userid and locationid, is

```
newFollow = Follow.new(:user_id => userid, :location_id => locationid)
newFollow.save
```

I'm getting the error unknown attribute: user_id.

any ideas? I'm really stuck. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a migration, `references` expects the field name without the `_id`, and it then appends `_id` to it. Right now, you're creating two columns: `user_id_id` and `location_id_id`.

Instead of these lines...

```
t.references :user_id
t.references :location_id
```

... you need these lines:

```
t.references :user
t.references :location
```

And once you've fixed your column names...

You don't have to manually create records in then "through" table. If you have a user, and you have a location, and your associations are setup correctly (`has_many follows; has_many :locations, through: :follows`), you can simply use

```
user.locations << location
```

This will automatically create the joining record.